# Generate date from serial number

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, date, formula

I have a customer which provides dates to us as serial numbers.  They gave us an Excel formula for converting the serial number to date but we use SQL Server 2008 R2.  I was wondering if someone can tell me how to convert these numbers to date fields in SQL Server.

Excel formula:

```
=DATE(1900+INT(F2/1000),1,MOD(F2,1000))
```

Excel table:

```
Serial # (F2 cell)  | Date Value
---------------------------------
103078              | 3/19/2003
104077              | 3/17/2004
```

I need a statement in T-SQL that will take the number and calculate to the correct date result.

Comment: How are you taking the data from `Excel` to `SQL`?

Comment: is `F2` value stored in database?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, (@F2%1000)-1, LEFT(1900+(@F2/1000),4)+'0101')
```

Produces the correct date from the 2 example serial numbers. Obviously replace @F2 with whatever you're getting the F2 value from.

[Working on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3506e/4/0) (although I'm not sure how to make variables work on there, so the serial numbers are hard coded)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select dateadd(day, @f2 % 1000 - 1, dateadd(year, @f2 / 1000, '1900-1-1'))
```